# Getting counts within Time range

Tags: sql, r, plyr, reshape

My data is a basically a purchase list with Products , dates and customer ID . A sample data can be created as below -

```
custId=c('A','A','B','C','A','D','E','F','B','C','F')
ProductPurchase=c('Milk','Tea','Milk','Eggs','Coffee','sugar','Chicken','milk','Apple','sugar','eggs')
BuyDate=c('1-03-2014','4-05-2017','15-02-2015','23-04-2014','12-04-2017','23-5-2016','13-5-2012','5-05-2014','2-03-2017','03-03-2017','21-06-2017')
ExpiryDate=c('1-03-2017','4-05-2022','15-02-2017','12-05-2015','12-04-2022','12-7-2018','23-06-2015','15-06-2017','3-03-2020','2-05-2019','21-07-2019')
DummyD=data.frame(custId,ProductPurchase,BuyDate,ExpiryDate)
```

#### data output

```
  custId ProductPurchase    BuyDate ExpiryDate
1      A            Milk  1-03-2014  1-03-2017
2      A             Tea  4-05-2017  4-05-2022
3      B            Milk 15-02-2015 15-02-2017
4      C            Eggs 23-04-2014 12-05-2015
5      A          Coffee 12-04-2017 12-04-2022
6      D           sugar  23-5-2016  12-7-2018
```

I am looking to retrieve the customers who bought milk and bought again ( any product ) with +- 60 days of Expiry ( could be 60 days before or after expiry )

For example for the data below , output should look like

```
CustID   BoughtWithin60Days   ProductExpiry  ProductBought  Expiry Date     BuyD
A           yes                     Milk        Coffee      1-03-2017      12-04-2017
B           yes                     Milk         Apple      15-02-2017     2-03-2017
F           yes                     Milk        Eggs        15-06-2017     21-06-2017
```

Comment: Should be just an inner join

Comment: @maSTAShuFu - could help give an example pls ?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a `merge` question than a `reshape` question.

Here's a possible solution using "data.table".

Start with cleaning things up. You need proper dates, and you need to make sure your "ProductPurchase" column can be used for a merge.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DummyD)
DummyD[, c("ProductPurchase", "BuyDate", "ExpiryDate") := 
         list(tolower(ProductPurchase),
              as.Date(BuyDate, format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
              as.Date(ExpiryDate, format = "%d-%m-%Y"))][]
```

Create a subset of just those rows where the product purchased was "milk". Add two columns to that with your +/- 60 days from the expiration.

```
milk <- DummyD[ProductPurchase == "milk"][
  , c("Min", "Max") := list(ExpiryDate - 60, ExpiryDate + 60)]
```

Create a subset of all of the other products purchased.

```
others <- DummyD[ProductPurchase != "milk"]
```

Merge the two subsets on the "custId" column. Then, add an indicator column to say whether it was bought within 60 days by checking the buy date of the second product (BuyDate.y) with the "Min" and "Max" values calculated earlier.

```
out <- merge(milk, others, "custId")[, within60 := BuyDate.y - 60 > Min & BuyDate.y < Max][]
out
#    custId ProductPurchase.x  BuyDate.x ExpiryDate.x        Min        Max
# 1:      A              milk 2014-03-01   2017-03-01 2016-12-31 2017-04-30
# 2:      A              milk 2014-03-01   2017-03-01 2016-12-31 2017-04-30
# 3:      B              milk 2015-02-15   2017-02-15 2016-12-17 2017-04-16
# 4:      F              milk 2014-05-05   2017-06-15 2017-04-16 2017-08-14
#    ProductPurchase.y  BuyDate.y ExpiryDate.y within60
# 1:               tea 2017-05-04   2022-05-04    FALSE
# 2:            coffee 2017-04-12   2022-04-12     TRUE
# 3:             apple 2017-03-02   2020-03-03     TRUE
# 4:              eggs 2017-06-21   2019-07-21     TRUE
```

If you only want to return the "TRUE" values, then you can use:

```
out[(within60)]
```